# Отправка сериализованного объекта методом get(http)

Tags: java, android, get, объекты, serialize

**Нужно средствами http отправить объект в который входит массив.**
Перечитал и прогуглил уже много. Не могу понять как его отправить.
Насколько я понимаю, то этот байтовый массив нужно кастануть в стринг и отправлять его.

### **- Как получить байтовый массив сериализованного объекта ?**

```
/*
  Псевдокод 
*/

array[][]
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
 oos.writeObject(array);
```

Comment: возможно вам нужно отправить объект как body parameters?

Comment: @YuryPashkov Нет, сервер так настроен(не мной) что нужно передавать именно  как `?api=array=(и тут сам объект)`
Это я просто пример.

Comment: и объект должен быть сериализован как String?

Comment: @YuryPashkov байтовый массив нужно передать типа 
`"array=" + bytearray.toString;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для полного ответа на вопрос желательно знать API сервера (в каком виде ожидается объект) и иметь представление об отправляем объекте. Но постараюсь дать развернутый ответ исходя из возможных вариантов.

**Вариант 1.**
Сервер ожидает массив в URL в одном из следующих форматов

- Разделенные запятыми значения. Пример:`http://ex.com/doIt?array=el1,el2,el3`
- Повторяющееся имя параметра. Пример:`http://ex.com/doIt?array=el1&array=el2&array=el3`

Эти варианты подходят для передачи массива примитивных типов.

**Вариант 2.**
Сервер ожидает JSON массив или объект закодированный с помощью [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) или чего-то аналогичного. Пример:`http://ex.com/doIt?array=%5B%22el1%22%2C%22el2%22%2C%22el3%22%5D`

Подходит для сложных типов.

**Вариант 3.**
Сервер ожидает объект в бинарном виде закодированном в строке [Base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Пример:`http://ex.com/doIt?array=YmFzZTY0U3RyaW5n`
Для кодирования существуют стандартные реализации в [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) и [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) и сторонние, например от [Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

***Не по теме***
*Нижеследующее не относится к запросам не меняющим состояние данных на сервере (фильтрация и т.п.)*
Передача объекта для сохранения его на сервере с помощью GET запроса это плохой дизайн HTTP (или REST как кому нравится) API сервера. По нескольким причинам:

- GET метод по определению [стандарта](http://lib.ru/WEBMASTER/rfc2068/section-9.html#p1) должен быть [идемпотентным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Т.е. побочные эффекты от N > 0 идентичных запросов такие же, как от одиночного запроса.
- Существуют ограничения на длину URL браузерах, прокси и веб серверах.
- GET запросы могут быть закешированы.
- Краулер поисковика каким-то образом получивший такую ссылку может сделать кучу дублей в вашей БД.

Comment: По сути, правильный вариант - это под номером 3.
Но, я не могу найти, как массив перевести в байтовую последованность.
Как я думаю, то нужно сделать операцию
`array[][]
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
 oos.writeObject(array);`  А потом уже получить массив байтов 
`baos.toByteArray` и потом передать в Base64.
Правильно я думаю ?

Comment: Правильно, если сервер ожидает сериализованный Java объект.